# Football (soccer) mixed teams

Tags: rules, football, gender

Are there statutes governing professional football that prevent either club or national teams from deploying a mixed team of both men and women? Are such teams prohibited at all levels, or only under particular circumstances?

Comment: In Australia, at the lowest levels of the game, skilled women occasionally play in the same open age competition as men.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In leagues under the FA, [mixed football was extended to U16](http://www.thefa.com/news/2014/may/mixed-football-extension-agreed-u16), and afterwards [to U18](http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/32848757).

Also, in Italy, it is allowed for females to play with males [until 16 years old](http://www.figc.it/it/3813/31646/Impianti.shtml).

Each federation can set its own guidelines.

Comment: Also, from the first linked article: 'Denmark has no age limit for mixed teams, Netherlands and Switzerland split players at 19 while Germany and Italy do likewise at 17. "Uefa annually asks all European countries to declare their mixed football age limit," said the FA's national development manager for women's football Rachel Pavlou.'